# How can i use REF type in PL/SQL Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I have this code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_abonnement_type AS OBJECT
(
  ref_abonnement_type NUMBER,
  type_abonne         VARCHAR(50),
  MEMBER PROCEDURE DISPLAY
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_abonnement AS OBJECT
(
  ref_abonnement           NUMBER,
  date_debut               DATE,
  type_abonnement          REF t_abonnement_type,
  MEMBER PROCEDURE DISPLAY
);
```

What i want to do is just create the members procedures DISPLAY declared.
So i did it this way :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_abonnement AS
  MEMBER PROCEDURE DISPLAY IS
    BEGIN
        /* SOME CODE */
        type_abonnement.display;
    END;
END;
```

And i get this error

```
PLS-00536: Navigation through REF variables is not supported in PL/SQL.
```

So how can i deal with REF in PL/SQL statements ? 
Thanks

Comment: A `ref` is a pointer to a record in a SQL (i.e. database) object table. Consequently Oracle supports them in SQL but not in PL/SQL. It's a bit confusing, but Type bodies are PL/SQL not SQL (different modules in the kernel code). If you want less vague advice you need to post the body of `MEMBER PROCEDURE DISPLAY` and whatever additional code needed for us to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @APC, it's not possible to  directly use `member` function of a `Object` to another using `REF` since Oracle supports them in SQL but not in PL/SQL.

However if I look at your requirement from a different angle, I could see you are trying to simply make use of Procedure used in an Object to another Object. Means if I forget the referencing part and create a scenario which could satisfy the referencing concept then it should "OK".

This is possible. Yes..!!! This can be done. The only thing I did here is to make the two Objects as parent-child to achieve `referencing`. See demo below:

```
--Parent Object
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_abonnement_type AS OBJECT
(
  ref_abonnement_type NUMBER,
  type_abonne         VARCHAR(50),
   MEMBER FUNCTION DISPLAY return varchar2
) NOT FINAL; 

-- Member Funtion Body
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_abonnement_type
AS
  MEMBER FUNCTION DISPLAY 
  return varchar2
  IS
  BEGIN
   return ('Hi');
  END DISPLAY;
END;
```

Testing my Parent Object:

```
SQL> SELECT t_abonnement_type(1,'a').display() col from DUAL;  

    COL
    ---
    Hi
```

Child Object to achieve **referencing** concept

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_abonnement 
under t_abonnement_type  
(
  ref_abonnement           NUMBER,
  date_debut               DATE,
  MEMBER function V_DISPLAY return varchar2
);

--Member function 
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_abonnement
AS
  MEMBER Function V_DISPLAY  return varchar2
  IS
  var varchar2(10);
  BEGIN      
     var:=  t_abonnement_type(1,'A').display(); --Calling Parent Member function here
     return('Called from Child Object -->'||var);
  END;
END;
```

Testing my Child Object to check if the parent `Member function` is referenced or not:

```
SQL> SELECT T_ABONNEMENT(1,'A',2,TO_DATE('30-JUN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY')).V_DISPLAY() COL FROM DUAL;

Col
---
Called from Child Object -->Hi
```

Note I haven't used overloading done in your code as I feel overloading makes the stuff harder to understand as an individual as well as for compiler.

Comment: Reasonable guess at what the OP was trying to achieve. I salute your willingness to invest your energy :)

Comment: @APC Thanks for your kind comments.